# Error while loading ListView with contact groups - IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I am loading a `ListView` with all contact groups. Following is the code I have written for that:

Code from `GroupActivity.java`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_group);
    Cursor groupCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.Groups._ID,
                    ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE}, null, null, null
    );
    ListView groupListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactList);
    groupListView.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, R.id.contactList, groupCursor, new String[]{
            ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE
    }, new int[] {R.id.list_item}, 0
    ));

    groupListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(me, "Notification will be sent soon" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my view:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/contactList"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Quite simple. But when I run the application, I am getting an exception with cause as follows:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column title
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:167)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:413)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:462)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:405)
        at com.tariq.mysms.GroupActivity.onCreate(GroupActivity.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
```

I wonder why it is calling `title` as invalid column although I have clearly queried for that column too. Is that because of the view type I am using in `to` argument? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong URI - you are using `ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI` but should be using [`ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Groups.html#CONTENT_URI).

The error you are getting is because `ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE` is not a valid column for `ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI`